# logical statements that handle NA

Tags: r

I have an object `a` which contains value NA .

```
a= as.numeric(comb1[2,])
[1] NA NA
```

Now I want to create a variable which will take value 0 if `a[1]<.4 & a[2]>.4` and 1 otherwise .  But if I run the following command , it produces `NA` :

```
ifelse((a[1]<.4 & a[2]>.4),0,1)
[1] NA
```

But I want it to be 1 , if it is also `NA` .

How can I do that ?

Comment: `ifelse(!is.na(a[1]) && !is.na(a[2]) && a[1]<.4 && a[2]>.4, 0, 1)`

Comment: @PingJin Thank you . It works . But could you please explain how does it work ?

Comment: Do not use `ifelse` if you don't need a vectorized approach (e.g., don't use it together with `&&`). Use `if` and `else`.

Comment: @Roland is `if(!is.na(a[1]) && !is.na(a[2]) && a[1]<.4 && a[2]>.4){
   x=0
}else x=1`  correct ?

Comment: @Munira Yes, and you can even assign this, e.g., `x <- if(...) {...} else {...}`